# Unit testing a non-class Groovy function using Gradle

Tags: unit-testing, gradle, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

I was given a Jenkins Library project, and I'd like to write some unit tests for it. I'm currently using the [Jenkins Pipeline Shared Libraries Gradle Plugin](https://github.com/mkobit/jenkins-pipeline-shared-libraries-gradle-plugin) which [sets up source paths for unit and integration tests](https://github.com/mkobit/jenkins-pipeline-shared-libraries-gradle-plugin/blob/3cae6e9f3b10cfeec4d989f7a2e72956ed584f1a/src/main/kotlin/com/mkobit/jenkins/pipelines/SharedLibraryPlugin.kt#L135).

The source file I want to test is located at `src/org/example/pipeline/Terraform.groovy` and looks like:

```
package org.example.pipeline

def terraformNewWorkspace(String env, Map config) {
    def tfWSCreate = """
        #!/bin/bash
        set -e

        terraform workspace new ${env} || true
        terraform workspace select ${env}
        terraform workspace list
    """
    if (config.currentWorkingDirectory != null) {
        dir("${config.currentWorkingDirectory}") {
          sh(returnStatus: false, script: tfWSCreate)
        }
    } else {
      sh(returnStatus: false, script: tfWSCreate)
    }
}
```

and I've created a `test/unit/groovy/example/PipelineTests.groovy` which looks like the following:

```
import static org.example.pipeline.Terraform.terraformNewWorkspace as terraformNewWorkspace

class TerraformUnitTests extends GroovyTestCase {

   void testNewWorkspace() {
    terraformNewWorkspace("dev", [currentWorkingDirectory: "/tmp/test"])
   }
}
```

However I get a `groovy.lang.MissingMethodException at PipelineTests.groovy` when I try to execute this using `gradle test`. I've also tried the following as some documentation seems to indicate functions that are not part of a class get added in Groovy to a class with the name of the file, but I get the same exception about a missing method.

```
import org.example.pipeline.Terraform
...
t = new Terraform()
t.terraformNewWorkspace("dev", [currentWorkingDirectory: "/tmp/test"])
```

What is the correct way to import and test this individual function using gradle/groovy?

Answer (score 0):

It was a simple syntax error. I forgot to use `def` for my variable:

```
import org.example.pipeline.Terraform

class TerraformUnitTests extends GroovyTestCase {
   void testNewWorkspace() {
    def t = new Terraform()
    t.terraformNewWorkspace("dev", [currentWorkingDirectory: "/tmp/test"])
   }
}
```